# "Unable to create project" error given right after install

Tags: unity-game-engine

I previously had Unity Hub around a year ago and uninstalled it. I went and deleted the old directory in the Program Files folder and then installed the newest version of Unity Hub. When I launched it, the old directory that I used to use for my old projects was already in the box. When I tried to create the project, it said "Unable to create project". Is there some other thing I'm supposed to delete also? I don't know where the old version used to save that kind of information, but I think it has to be deleted for the newer one to work. Unfortunately, I don't remember what version I had before. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: You should better try looking for this kind of help on some official issue tracker of the tool

Answer (score 0):

You should never delete software's files without uninstalling them. Try to uninstall Unity Hub with the apposite feature and re-install the latest version.

Comment: what do you mean the opposite feature

Comment: Sorry, I meant apposite